# Version Control for projects. Net

Tags: c, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I need a simple version control, practical and preferably free, I count on the help?

Comment: Don't you know how to use Google?

Comment: I really did not know what to use then asked, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have come to the right place.

Go here...its free for 5 users and its in the cloud so you will never lose your code.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information#

Otherwise there is GITHUB free for open source

https://github.com/

And if you want a local source control there is Subversion or SVN

http://subversion.tigris.org/

Enjoy